# Qt Creator creates both a debug and a release folder inside the designated debug folder

Tags: c++, qt, debugging, qt-creator

I am using the default build directory in Qt Creator which is something like **build-project-blah-blah-Debug**. However, when I build my app in debug mode both a **debug** and and a **release** folder are created inside. If I set the build directory as **build-project-blah-blah** for both the debug and release builds Qt Creator does not behave properly, i.e. it complaints and it does not clean the built files.

Comment: Check my comment from [\[Qt\]: #13807: Build directory creates additional debug and release folders in windows only](https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTCREATORBUG-13807) for more details.

Answer (score 10):

I deduced the solution from [this answer to the reverse question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4563512/726156).
In your .pro file, add the following line to prevent the subdirectories being created:

```
CONFIG -= debug_and_release debug_and_release_target
```

This issue only occurs on Windows, not on Unix-based OS's. Windows sets these flags by default, whereas Unix implementations of QT don't. To me it was mainly a problem due to compatibility of my project between both environments.

Answer (score 1):

You can choose folder for debug and release builds on the *projects mode (Ctrl + 5)*

There you have a combo box which says "Edit build configuration", and lets you choose *Release* or *Debug*, and then you can edit the build directory of each one

Comment: I'm having the same issue as biologist. The problem is that inside that build directory of your solution, there have been created subdirs for debug and release. I don't have that problem on Mac.